# Scala Intellij not recognizing TODO comments

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 2021.2 Community Edition Build #C 212.4746.92, built on July 27, 2021.

The IDE sometimes recognizes comments "//TODO", "// TODO" and sometimes not. They're recognized when they are printed in yellow.
When these comments aren't recognized I add or remove a space but it works just for some minutes ... then they gone grey again ...

Does anybody knows how to fix this?

EDIT: Config in Intellij Editor / TODO

- Treat indented text on the following lines as part of the same TODO (MARKED)
- Under Patterns:
  \btodo\b.* (case sensitive not marked)
  \bfixme\b.* (case sensitive not marked)

Comment: Please share TODO settings: https://i.imgur.com/TgjS4Vo.png Do you have some strange patterns here?

Comment: I have the same config as your image ... it's weird ... (I edited the post and added the configuration)